# How do I connect my washing machine's waste pipe to a small connector?

Tags: washing-machine

I've just moved house (UK), and the space for the washing machine doesn't have a waste pipe. Instead, it has an odd looking connecting pipe that looks like something fits over it. How do I connect my washing machine, which has a normal waste pipe, to this? - I've tried Googling but can't find anything that looks like this image.

The previous occupants had a washing machine here, so we know it's possible! The only other thing in the washing machine gap is the cold water inlet.

[image: Washing machine connection 1]

[image: Washing machine connection 2]

This is the back of my washing machine - its waste pipe is on the right:

[image: Back of washing machine]

Comment: What's a "normal" waste pipe? That nipple would accept several sizes of tubing.

Comment: @isherwood I've only ever installed washing machines where the waste pipe slots **into** the waste pipe on the wall.. I assumed I'd need some sort of special connector to attach it **over** the thing in the image in order to make it watertight.. is that not the case?

Comment: Forgive those of us in the US... Is this the end of the hose coming out of your washer? Could you [edit] to add a picture of what it's supposed to connect to? Or, if I've got that backwards, add a pic of the other end that should be connected.

Comment: @FreeMan I've added an image of the back of the washing machine. The first two images are of the pipe at the house.

Comment: It appears to me that the waste water hose is on the right edge of the pic of the back of the washer. Does that not fit onto the large, unoccupied end of the light-grey barbed fitting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like a connector used to lengthen the waste pipe. It is designed to accept the common waste pipe sizes and most waste pipes have a flexible end - visible on the waste pipe on the back of the machine.

Once you have checked that that pipe goes into a suitable drain (with U bend) and it is not too long (6 feet is a usual max, but do read the machine instructions), and that extension is not blocked then it should work fine.

Based on the comment:
if you want the security of adding hose clamps, then do not make them too tight. I would make sure to push the pipe fully deep over the barbs or ridges - you can see the bulge caused by the ridges on the other side already.

Comment: Would you expect that a clamp is needed there?

Comment: @isherwood well you can add one, but if you make it too tight you can cause issues. Do note the other side shows no evidence of a clamp and the fractional bulge where the pipe is going over the barbs.

Answer (score 1):

looking at that grey plastic thing I'm seeing what looks like an air-addmittance valve in the middle, with threaded hose barbs screwed into either end.

presumably the way to use it is to attach your waste hose to the hose barbs.
if the size is wrong you should be able to unscrew the hose barb and replace it with one (or a collection of fittings) that is the right size.

The presense of the AAV in the middle is mysterious it's possible that it's being used to prevent siphoning because the hose is longer than usual.

washing machine waste hoses work at low pressure, usually a clamp is not needed unless there is something pulling on the hose